# Javascript history does not work

Tags: javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  displayRecentUrls("recentUrls");
});

function displayRecentUrls(divName) {
    var popup = document.getElementById(divName);
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    popup.appendChild(ul);
    var microsecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    var oneWeekAgo = (new Date).getTime() - microsecondsPerWeek;
    history.search({
      'text': '',              
      'startTime': oneWeekAgo  
    },
    function(historyItems) {
      for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; ++i) {
        var url = historyItems[i].url;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        ul.appendChild(li);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(url));
        li.appendChild(a);
      }

    });
}
```

I wrote the code above to generate the browsing history for one week. It does not work. I'm new to Javascript so I may have made a silly mistake.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more info? Are you receiving any errors? Is there any output at all? You can check for errors using the web developer console in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: The silly mistake is not describing the issue in greater detail.

Comment: The `history` object doesn't have a `search` method.

Comment: @sachleen well that may be the problem, then what object should I use instead to get history url list?

Comment: @hackNightly it seems the history object does not have a search method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot get browser history. What you can do however, is see if the user has visited certain URLs or not. Here's an [example](http://www.dicabrio.com/javascript/steal-history.php).

If you just want to go one page back, `document.referrer` gives you the page the user came from.

Comment: well my goal is to grab my own browsing history and analyse how frequently I go to certain sites.

Comment: +1, interesting tactic in that link but I don't think it works in most modern browsers. (chrome/IE simulating all the way down to quirks mode IE7 don't change the style unless the link is clicked via that page)

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng you won't be able to do that using just JS. You'll want to write a plugin for your browser. There are quite a few Chrome extensions that do the job, like [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejifodhjoeeenihgfpjijjmpomaphmah?hl=en).